# I'm trying to connect to mysql with vb 2010 express, Access denied

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wamp

i have already read a ton of posts about connecting vb 2010 express to Mysql in Wamp, but none solved my problem :P.
The thing is that i have a local Mysql server running, to which i do connect with no  problems in PHP and MySQL Workbench, but when i tried to connect with vb 2010 express i found out i had to Import the connector and then build the code accordingly.

I think my code is ok, but still getting the message "WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe Error: 0 : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Here's the code:

```
 Private Sub CheckPayments()

    Try
        myPassword = ""

        myConnstr = "Server=localhost;Database=kiosk;Uid=root;Pwd=myPassword"
        myQuery = "select * from products where deleted = 0"

        Dim myConn As New MySqlConnection(myConnstr)
        Dim myDa As New MySqlDataAdapter(myQuery, myConn)


        If myDa.Fill(myDs) Then ' 1 significa que a ligação foi efetuada com sucesso
            mysqldump.DataSource = myDs.Tables(0)
        End If

        myConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Stuck in project with this error, need help quick !! 
Thanks in advance for any help you can give me :)

BR, Carlos Mendes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps out someone who needs to connect VB2010 Express to MySQL.

This code displays MySQL data in a DataGridView object. Connections problem solved :).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles Button1.Click
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Database=<your db>;User ID=<your user>;Password=<your password>;")
    Dim sql As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM <your table>", con)

    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

    Dim DataAdapter1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter()

    con.Open()

    DataAdapter1.SelectCommand = sql

    DataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "<DataGridView table name>")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds

    DataGridView1.DataMember = "<DataGridView table name>"

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Import Connecter, is better and good way with out any trouble!

mysql-connector-net-6.4.5-noinstall

Then go to 
Project -> Add Reference -> TAB-Browse

Browse where you save "mysql-connector-net-6.2.2"

Select only mysql.data.dll

Then use your Connection command to connect WAMP MYSQL!
Thats It..